# Cypress iframe is not loading 100% when started from cypress

Tags: iframe, cypress

We have a page in our application where you can submit your cv's and apply for a job.
When the page is loaded outside cypress, it renders correctly with all the fields but when loaded from cypress, it is not loaded fully.
I tried with waits, with resolution changes, nothing works. As you can see in the cypress picture, it only displays the first 2 text input fields. I cannot scroll down, i cannot scroll into view.

[image: Cypress Page]

[image: Normal Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to have a solution: wrap the iframe into an element and then interacting with the elements inside:

`cy.get('#iFrameResizer0').its('0.contentDocument.body').then(cy.wrap).find('#inputFirstName')`